# Variable indefinida cuando es definida

Tags: php

```
<?php

 $dominio = "#";
 $username = "#";
 $password = "#";
 $conexion = new mysqli($servidor,$username,$password);
 if($conexion -> connect_error){
    die("Conexion fallida: ". $conexion -> connect_error);
 }else{
    echo 'Conexion ejecutada exitosamente';
 }

?>
```

Me da este error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: servidor in /storage/ssd4/514/9093514/public_html/db_connect.php on line 6

Pero un así se ejecuta el echo por lo que no se si sirve o no

Comment: Como no defines $servidor, te muestra el warning correspondiente de php y se toma como valor "", por lo que le pasas como servidor "" a mysqli y por defecto es localhost:3306, por lo que si tienes el servicio de mysql o mariadb en el mismo servidor, funcionará.

Comment: Gracias,no me habia dado cuenta de este percance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te esta diciendo que no existe la variable servidor, porque no la definiste... tu tienes definido la variable "dominio" solo bastaria con cambiar "dominio" por "servidor" tal cual asi:

```
<?php

$servidor = "#"; //Parte del codigo editada
$username = "#";
$password = "#";
$conexion = new mysqli($servidor,$username,$password);
if($conexion -> connect_error){
    die("Conexion fallida: ". $conexion -> connect_error);
}else{
    echo 'Conexion ejecutada exitosamente';
}

?>
```

Comment: Gracias, estaba distraido y no me di cuenta

Comment: No hay de que... Si solucione tu problema marca mí respuesta con la palomita sobre la flecha hacia arriba, así saldra que ya fue respondida y que está solucionado, saludos :)